# How can i close and start again app programmatically?

Tags: java, android

In my application I want close my app and start again it programically and for this I write below codes.
But in my code just close my app and not start again it?

**My code:**

```
private void exitFromApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you exiting from app and start it again?

Comment: @TominB, in my app I use VIP users, I want when buy my app first close it and starts again for run VIP users features. can you help me?

Comment: After Buying y should you close that application Just give Intent to the First Screen and And Finish All Activities working in BAckground

Comment: @TominB, can you send to me code? because I am amateur and really need your help. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of Closing the Application

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_STARTACTIVITY.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_STARTACTIVITY.class);
startActivity(intent);
finishAffinity();
finish();
```

The above two method can be used to start Your base activity by removing all background activities

Comment: Hey thanks my friend, your one method help to me. Thanks dear